# why my front end(react) and back-end(express) is not connecting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

my front and back-end is not connecting. its show **xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:3000/payments/create?total=12999 404 (Not Found)** error. for more info i provide necesary code below.

**this is my index.js file of backend(express).**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const stripe="   "

const app=express()
app.use(cors({origin:true}))
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send('hello world')
})

app.post('/payments/create',async(req,res)=>{
//   console.log("api is working")
  
    const total=req.query.total
     console.log('payment req recievd is',total)
   
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntent.create({
        amount:total,
        currency:"usd"
    })
    res.status(201).send({
        
        clientSecrat:paymentIntent.client_secret
    })
})
exports.api=functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

**this is my axios.js file...**

```
import axios from 'axios'
const instance=axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:5001/challange-c1266/us-central1/api' 
}
)
export default instance
```

**this is my payment.js file,where i want to use data from back-end,when person click on payment button than person clientSecret change true to real ID.**

```
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
            console.log("use effect is working")
            const getClientSecret = async () => {
                console.log("get client sec is is working")
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
                })
                // console.log('response is >>>>>>>>>>>',response)
                // console.log(response.data)
                setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
            }
            getClientSecret()
        }, [basket])
        console.log('the secrate is >>>>>>>>', clientSecret)
```

**but when i click on payment button i am getting error in console which i shown below.**
localhost:3000 is my react server...

```
 xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:3000/payments/create?total=12999 404 (Not Found)createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
        at createError (createError.js:16)
        at settle (settle.js:17)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:69)
```

Comment: I think it is because u are using params? POST wont send query. U should put variables in the http body.

Comment: even if i remove params still getting same errro ....gi-hyun-nam

Comment: But the route in the URL doesn't exist for the back end

Comment: http://localhost:5001/challange-c1266/us-central1/api is my backend url....when i type this in crome its gives me HELLO WORLD also.  Aviv Lo

Answer (score 1):

Your React code is running at

```
http://localhost:3000
```

And when you make API call via axios it will take the same port for api call
You have to pass the port `5001` in the API call.

```
const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `localhost:5001/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
})
```

Going forward you can use generic baseURL to make the API calls

```
BaseUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ":5001/";
```

and use

```
const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${BaseUrl}payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
})
```

Comment: thank you so much  for Anup... but i get another error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"